# Class "Routes" not found laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Before Everything is working fine,When I added a route `Routes::get('orders',[OrderController::class, 'index']);` and then I optimize the laravel using  `php artisan optimize` this through an error and I have no idea why it's coming, I double check each and everything but this error is far different from the normal error of importing class and correct routes

its imported web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

```
   


   Error 

  Class "Routes" not found

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\Scripting_Language_project\routes\web.php:87
     83▕     Route::put('update-product/{id}',[ProductController::class , 'update']);
     84▕     Route::get('delete-product/{id}',[ProductController::class , 'delete']);
     85▕     Route::put('update-order/{id}',[UserController::class , 'updateOrder']);
     86▕
  ➜  87▕     Routes::get('orders',[OrderController::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are extra 's' in [Route](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing). Try change to

```
Route::get('orders',[OrderController::class, 'index']);
```